# R: sudden unused argument error with TwitterR package

Tags: r, twitter

Only last week I have successfully used the below script:

```
library(twitteR)
tweets <- search('keyword', n=1500, lang="en", since=NULL, until=NULL, retryOnRateLimit=10)
```

Without me changing anything, it stopped working. I cleaned my environment, restarted R, but same result. Then I and tried the following:

```
library(twitteR)
tweets <- search('keyword', n=1500, lang="en", retryOnRateLimit=10)
```

A google search yielded the information that windows user should include an additional argument. After environment clean and restart I tried this:

```
library(twitteR)
tweets <- search('keyword', n=1500, lang="en", retryOnRateLimit=10, cainfo='cacert.pem')
```

The error 'unused argument' still persists. Has the TwitteR package been up-dated? I have no idea where to even start looking to fix the bug. Any ideas? pointers?
Thanks!

Comment: search is a base function, have you tried searchTwitter() ?

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. Will try that one. Though I have the feeling that the Twitter authentication up-date is the problem. Strange because the up-date happened several months ago. Found 2 useful websites.http://diggdata.in/post/50938118301/fetching-twitter-data-in-r-with-oauth-handshake and http://davetang.org/muse/2013/04/06/using-the-r_twitter-package/

Answer (score 1):

Sebastians very useful comment gave an indication that the package probably was up-dated and my previous code was outdated. Glad it worked as long as it did after the up-date. The following script now works again:

```
library(twitteR)
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
consumerKey = "your consumer key" 
consumerSecret = "your variable consumer secret" 
access_token = "your access token"
access_secret = "your access secret"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey,
                consumerSecret,
                access_token,
                access_secret)
tweets <- searchTwitter('keyword', n=1500, lang="en", since=NULL, until=NULL, retryOnRateLimit=10)
```

The consumer secret consumer key, access token, and access secret can be found in individual the Twitter application that needs to be set up ( https://dev.twitter.com/apps )